# Use controller property with link-to in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a navigation controller and template for which I want to be able to change the back link url from another route.

This is possible by using `this.controllerFor` and setting a property with `set('backUrl')`.

```
// products.product route
actions: {
  didTransition: function(){
    this.controllerFor('navigation').set('backUrl', this.router.generate('products') );
  }
}
```

In the navigation template I want to use `link-to`, because when using an `a`-tag the page reloads.

```
// navigation template
<a {{bind-attr href=backUrl}}>Go back</a>
```

The problem is that I can't give a URL to `link-to`, nor an array with the arguments.

So my question is: How to set a property on the nav controller that I can use with `link-to`.

Comment: Why are you supplying a URL and not just the route name and parameters? If you're navigating within your application, the URL isn't necessary.

Comment: I know, that's why I'm looking for a way to pass the route name and parameters. But now that you're stating it like this I think I should just use an object with `routeName, context, options` attributes just like the `link-to` function needs.